# Confusion over sendTransaction vs contract methods

Tags: contract-development, sendtransaction

I'm building a UI that talks to a smart contract and I'm using contract methods.

```
const data = await contract.methods.buyCredits().send({
        from: account,
        gas: 233000,
        value: choice.value,
      });
```

But noticed in several questions, the usage of `sendTransaction`.

Is the difference that `sendTransaction` is just a raw wallet to contract, wallet to wallet sending of Ether — not a contract method call?
web3.eth.sendTransaction or contract methods

**What is the difference?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can technically call a contract function **also** via `sendTransaction`, by specifying the encoded function-call in the `data` field (as explained in [the official documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction)).

For example:

```
const transaction = contract.methods.func(arg1, arg2, arg3);
const receipt = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    value: someValue,
    from: accountAddress,
    to: transaction._parent._address,
    gas: transaction.estimateGas({from: accountAddress, value: someValue}),
    data: transaction.encodeABI()
});
```

Of course, as shown in your question, you can just as well execute the function directly with `send`.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `sendTransaction` over calling a contract methods directly? Is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: @GN.: See the bottom line that I added a second before your comment.

Comment: @GN.: There is a reason though. Typically, you cannot really use `send`, unless your account is unlocked on the node that you're communicating with (like, when you use Truffle & Ganache). However, since this is not desirable (for security reasons), in order to sign transactions, you need to use `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction` followed by `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction`, where the former is called in a similar manner shown in my answer above.